# Implementing Code Conditionally in R Based on Features of Dataset

Tags: r, if-statement, variables, conditional-statements

I'm looking to streamline my code, and minimize manual tweaks depending on the data set I run through it. I.e. I receive batches of data by country - but each country is slightly different in terms of fields and field names, so requires tweaking each time I run a new country. I would like to eliminate the tweaks and do some selective coding. (Many of the challenges I handle easily with ifelse(), but haven't been able to do a conditional mutate for example).

This is a logic question, so please let me know if I should have uploaded a data set.

This is a new example, I just added. I realized since the one I had used was a mutate, there were many tools to answer the question. In this example, I am dealing with data from various countries, each df with varying dimensionality, which I will want to keep. I of course, could use different code for each, but I think it would be cleaner if I used the same code, but it accommodated various country data.

I have created a version of this using mutate with ifelse, creating variables for these non-common dimensions and that works. I'm wondering if there is an alternative in R where I can run select snippets of code (and a good answer may be, there is not that option inside pipes). [I know how to do with with separate sets of code and if {} else{}.

Keep in mind, this is part of a much larger block of code that I need all the countries to run though...this is just an illustrative subset.

```
# As you can see, I comment out each countries unique variables (and spelling!)
P_Region_HP_Brand <- P_Region_HP %>%
  left_join(M_brand) %>%
  left_join(M_prodcat) %>%
  group_by(Calendar_Year, Calendar_Quarter, Calendar_Month, Calendar_Month_txt, Date, 
           region_b_frcst5, region_b_frcst7, Country, country_b, 
           BrandSummary, rank_m, Launch_Year, Launch_Month, Model, PriceSegment, SumProdCat, ProductCategory, True_Wireless, ProductType,
           # SPORTS, VOICE.ASSISTANT.FUNCTION          # JPN
           # Sports, Heart.Rate.Sensor                 # EU3
           # HEARTMON, WTRRSST                         # USA
           Sports, DIST_TYP                          # CHN
           ) %>%
  summarize(Dollars = sum(Dollars),                  # ALL (inc USA)
            Local_Currency = sum(Local_Currency),    # ALL
            Units = sum(Units)) %>%
  select(Calendar_Year, Calendar_Quarter, Calendar_Month, Calendar_Month_txt, Date, Launch_Year, Launch_Month,
         region_b_frcst5, region_b_frcst7, Country, country_b, 
         BrandSummary, Model, PriceSegment, SumProdCat, ProductCategory, True_Wireless, ProductType, 
         Units, Dollars, Local_Currency, rank_m,             # ALL (inc USA)
         # HEARTMON, WTRRSST,                          # USA
         # SPORTS, VOICE.ASSISTANT.FUNCTION            # JPN
         # Sports, Heart.Rate.Sensor                   # EU3
         Sports, DIST_TYP                            # CHN
         ) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  arrange(Country, desc(Date), desc(Local_Currency))
```

Does anyone know a solution for this that will allow me to keep my code simple enough? & run select lines for given countries?

Comment: Instead of the nested ifelse  statements, just use the `format()` function.  If Date is truly a date object, then try: `format(Raw_Data%Date, "%B")` and  `format(Raw_Data%Date, "%Y")`

Comment: Thank you Dave2e. That makes sense. It is actually a 'chr' string. It may be convertible, I honestly didn't think about that for this example, so great suggestion I will look into for this particular piece of code. However, this is just an illustrative example from a subset of code, my question is more broadly, how would one handle this practically across a variety of examples, many not including dates, but other types of data.

Comment: It is difficult to provide an very general answer, but there couple potential options, dplyr does offer the `mutate_if()` function or enclose your statements which are conditional inside `if` statements.

Comment: Understood...if you have time (no worries), how would you do this specifically for the above example (given the date is not a date object) using mutate_if or otherwise?

Comment: Thanks, I took a shot at improving my example, as Dave2e pointed out, the original examples actually had more straight forward simple examples.